# Create multiple directories in Android

Tags: java, android

This is my directory structure on my Android sdcard

```
 sdcard/alQuranData/Reader1/Surah
```

Here is my code to make Directories

```
File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "alQuranData/Reader1/Surah");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SDCardRoot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) {
                    Log.d("DIRECTORY CHECK", "Directory doesnt exist creating directory");
                    SDCardRoot.mkdir();
                }
```

Now `alQuranData` is already created in my `sdcard` root. If i only create Reader1 directory than it works fine, but when is add `Reader1/Surah` than it did not create.

I also tried `mkdirs()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: yes there is `sdcard` in my root dir

Comment: what happens when you use the above code little bit clear?What happens when you use the mkdirs() in this code?

Comment: Did you check the SDCardRoot file obj value ?is it same as expected directory structure?

Comment: after creating directories i put a message in `Logcat` that `"Directory created successfully"` but when i look in `sdcard` it dont show me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17730/discussion-between-stranger-and-antarix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting any error or exception. Please try to check the return value of `mkdirs()` method call. ALso try the following code:

```
File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/alQuranData/Reader1/Surah");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SDCardRoot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) {
    Log.d("DIRECTORY CHECK", "Directory doesnt exist creating directory");
    SDCardRoot.mkdirs();
}
```

Please also check that you have added following permission in manifest file:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I just tested the following code and it is working on my end:

```
File SDCardRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() + "/alQuranData/Reader1/Surah");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SDCardRoot.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) {
    Log.d("DIRECTORY CHECK",
            "Directory doesnt exist creating directory "
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .toString());
    boolean outcome = SDCardRoot.mkdirs();

    Log.d("DIRECTORY CHECK",
            "outcome for " + SDCardRoot.getAbsolutePath() + "     "
                    + outcome);
}
```

I have added alQaranData folder manually as mentioned in your post and added the permission and it start working at my end. Please check this code.

Comment: ya have done that , also able to create single directory but i want to create multiple directories at a time.See my comments

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.....)

```
  private void createSdCatalogs(String str1){
    //str1 = "/alQuranData"
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + str1);
boolean success = false;
if (!folder.exists()) {
    success = folder.mkdir();
    Log.v("Adding line", "/");
}}
private void createSdCatalogs(String str2)   { 
//str2 = "/alQuranData/Reader1";
File folder1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + str2);
boolean success1 = false;
if (!folder1.exists()) {
    success1 = folder1.mkdir();
    Log.v("Adding line", "/");
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for your post, but I am passing `"alQuranData/Reader1/Surah"` as parameter string. So i need to create this folders at a time , if already exists than skip and create next folder

Comment: ok, Just add all string parameters to your FolderCreators, it may be different methods... and then in each of them add "return" methods, which will return you the result of creation...

Comment: you din't understood my question. I am passing this `"alQuranData/Reader1/Surah"` whole string as a parameter at once

Comment: Have you gotten answer on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Using Java you cannot create multiple directories all at once. You will need to declare a folder name one by one and proceed to create a directory. So first create

1. alQuranData
2. alQuranData/Reader1/
3. alQuranData/Reader1/Surah

Using the same piece of code you have provided.

Comment: than can you tell me what `mkdirs()` does ?

Comment: mkdirs() Creates the directory named by abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories. So if you give this command, it may not create the end directory, but some non existent directory before it. e.g. if you give alQuranData/Reader1/Surah, it may create alQuranData or Reader1 if not present!

Comment: hi roy, mkdirs() can be used for creating multiple directory. please check my answer..

Answer (score -1):

By default there is no way in android to create multiple directory at once.
you have to create one by one and check is created or not.

**But I have created a below code to achieve similar objective. you can use to create multiple directory at once...**

```java
public static boolean recursivelyMakeDir(File endDirectory,File baseDir) {

        if (!baseDir.exists()){
            return false;
        }
        ArrayList<String> allDirectoryList = parseAndGetListDir(endDirectory.getAbsolutePath().substring(baseDir.getAbsolutePath().length()));

        File  currentDir = baseDir;

        for (int i=0; i< allDirectoryList.size() ; i++){

            File dir = new File(currentDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + allDirectoryList.get(i) );

            if (!dir.exists()){

                if (!dir.mkdir()){
                    return false;
                }
            }

            currentDir  = dir;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> parseAndGetListDir(String data) {

        ArrayList<String> allDirectoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean exit = false;
        String dir = "";

        for (int i=0; i<data.length() ; i++){

            if (data.charAt(i) == '/'){
                if (!dir.equals("")){
                    allDirectoryList.add(dir);
                    dir = "";
                }
            }else {
                dir = dir + data.charAt(i);
            }

        }

        if (!dir.equals("")){
            allDirectoryList.add(dir);
        }

        return allDirectoryList;
    }
```

**Usage :**

```java
// you 100% sure that this  directory is already exist.
File baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

// desire directory wanted to create.
File endDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"kkk/SSS/aaa/ddd/b");

if(recursivelyMakeDir(endDirectory ,baseDir )){

  // dir created sucessessfully
}else{
  // failed
}
```

Comment: `By default there is no way in android to create multiple directory at once.` In java it's [totally feasible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

Comment: Have you checked that dir.mkdir() create multiple directory at once in android. it always return false. I don't about java , but in android ,I have checked it. the question context is base on android framework not limit to java.

Comment: @SiddiqueMohdsaif `File#mkdir()` is a different method than `File#mkdirs()` (notice the **s** at the end).